# Excel conditional formatting linked cells blank formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have applied conditional formatting to a row so that when one of the cells in the row is not blank, it is highlighted. I have entered a formula into the first cell so that it is linked to another cell in another worksheet - this is causing the conditional formatting to kick in even though the source cell is blank. How can I stop the conditional formatting kicking in, unless the source cell is not blank? Many thanks.

Comment: I suppose you used `ISBLANK()`, try `=""` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A cell that contains a formula is always considered 'not blank'.

You need to change the condition in the conditional formatting to compare to nothing: `=""`. If the formula produces 'nothing', then the conditional formatting will understand that as such.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the row you want add the conditional formatting to
2. Click conditional formatting
3. Click + to add a new rule
4. Make sure the row you want is populated in "Apply to range"
5. You will want your rule type to be as follows:

   - Highlight cells with
   - Cell value
   - Not Equal to
   - =0
6. Add your custom formatting
7. Click "Done"